# Why do my radio buttons become not highlighted when I selected the next one in the list of questions

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am printing many questions from a database and need to have all the clicked radio buttons selected now just the last one clicked.

Tried giving them all unique values so they are all different but that hasnt worked.

```
<ul *ngFor="let question of questions[0]; let i = index">
    <form #userForm = "ngForm">


        <div *ngIf="question.Capability === Capability">
            <h3 class="SubCat">{{question.SubCategory}} {{question.Skill}}</h3>
                <div class="EandS">
                    <h4 class="skill">Skill</h4>
                    <h4 class="energy">Energy</h4>
                </div>


                <div class = "buttons">
                    <div class="skillButtons">
                        <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select your Skill Level" [(ngModel)]="skillLevel[i]" name="completedSkills[i]" >
                            <mat-radio-button  [value]="0" class="rbuttonSkill">0</mat-radio-button>
                            <mat-radio-button  [value]="1" class="rbuttonSkill">1</mat-radio-button>
                            <mat-radio-button  [value]="2" class="rbuttonSkill">2</mat-radio-button>
                            <mat-radio-button  [value]="3" class="rbuttonSkill" >3</mat-radio-button>
                            <mat-radio-button  [value]="4" class="rbuttonSkill" >4</mat-radio-button>
                        </mat-radio-group>
                    </div>

                    <div class="energyButtons">
                        <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select your Energy Level" [(ngModel)]="energyLevel[i]" name="completedEnergy[i]">
                                <mat-radio-button  [value]="1" class="rbuttonEnergy" >1</mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button  [value]="2" class="rbuttonEnergy" >2</mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button  [value]="3" class="rbuttonEnergy" >3</mat-radio-button>
                        </mat-radio-group>

                    </div>
                </div>

                    <strong>Seleted Answer : {{skillLevel[i]}}</strong>
                    <strong>Seleted Answer : {{energyLevel[i]}}</strong>

        </div>
    </form>
</ul>
<button  [disabled]="skillLevel[i]==undefined" mat-raised-button color="accent">save</button>

<pre>{{ skillLevel | json }}</pre>
<pre>{{ energyLevel | json }}</pre>
```

Need the last radio button from each section that was clicked to stay clicked even when moving onto the next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your radio groups have the same name: `completedSkills[i]`. If you want that `i` to be evaluated, you need an Angular expression:

```
[name]="'completedSkills-' + i"
```

for example.

Without the brackets around name, the value is just a literal string that Angular doesn't evaluate.

Comment: More likely what the OP needs is `[name]="completedSkills[i]"`.